# flutter bar charts show live data fetched from webpage

Tags: flutter

I want to plot bar charts to show live data fetched from webpage.
I have managed to get response from webpage in json format then convert it to List and plot the data, but it doesn't get refreshed.

Comment: https://github.com/JohannesMilke/fl_bar_chart_example

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 ways to achieve this.

1. Make self-calling a future method that calls itself until the screen is disposed of.
2. Create socket and listeners every time update data. You can listen to change and update the pie chart. Same as a real-time chat application.
3. You can use firebase's real-time database for this solution.Every time data update in schema,Application will state recalls via streams automatically